# How to find installed libraries in hadoop server?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, tensorflow, keras

I am currently working with hadoop server. Now , I have to train a neural network with libraries like keras, Tensorflow etc. I know there is spark libs already installed.  I just wanna check whether there are any other libs installed on hadoop server.  Our company has it's own hadoop server in a remote location.  Am not allowed to install any new libs and had to work with existing libs. Can you please let me know how to check whether there is any library that's installed in hadoop server already?

Comment: do you have access to this server? do you know how to use ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not a single server, and you actually need to check **all YARN NodeManagers** for any libraries, as that's where Spark runs. In a large cluster, that's not an easy task...

When you submit a Spark job, you can freely add your own `--files` and `--archives` to bring in any dependencies to your classpath. These flags will copy files locally into your Spark execution space, overwriting what's already in the cluster.

By default, Spark just uses whatever builtin classes there are, and those are typically contained in an archive file. You would need to inspect your Spark configuration files to determine where that is, download it from HDFS, then extract it out to determine any available libraries.

Or you ask the cluster administrator what version of Spark is installed, and if any extra libraries were added (typically the answer to that would be none). With the version information, go download Spark yourself and inspect its contents